# Run a solution in debug mode if MSBuild compilation is successful from the command line

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, powershell, msbuild

I am looking to improve my personal development process. I would like to create a batch file or similar that I can run from Windows PowerShell or the plain-old command line that does the following:

1. Compiles my solution (e.g. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe /m:8 "%CD%\MySolution.sln"`)
2. *If the compilation was successful*, run it in debug mode, attaching the visual studio debugger, otherwise stop.

In essence, I am trying to replicate the behavior of pressing F5 in Visual Studio, but invoked from the command line. Is this possible? The reason for all this, is that I find the VS UI responsiveness degrades significantly when invoking MSBuild commands from within the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

```
msbuild 

if($?) {
     # launch your process
     Debug-Process -name "<Your Process Name>"
}
```